# Как сделать для товаров URL вида domain.ru/products/some-product

Tags: php, веб-программирование, opencart, opencart3.x

У меня стоит OpenCart Version 3.0.2.0, в нем из коробки есть модуль/модификатор seo_url, у каждого товара в админке есть вкладка seo где можно прописать нужный seo url, в итоге урл будет вида domain.ru/category/subcategory/product

Либо же domain.ru/category/product

Но в итоге я получаю дубли страниц одного и того же товара, которые отображается как в верхней категории так и подкатегории.

Я бы хотел сделать ссылки у всех товаров одного вида domain.ru/products/some-product, независимо откуда я перехожу на карточку товара

Подскажите как этого добиться

Answer (score 0):

Дописывать моды или искать сео-расширения решающие подобные проблемы.

Вот [тут](https://isenselabs.com/posts/how-to-solve-the-duplicate-content-issue-in-opencart) очень хорошо описаны несколько вариантов решения дублей у товаров.

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916283/opencart-duplicate-url-keywords) ребята решали проблему дублей при нахождении товара в разных категориях одновременно.